# receiving error on MailApp.sendEmail when email list is in array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am receiving an error on apps script:- "Exception: The parameters (number[],String,String,(class)) don't match the method signature for MailApp.sendEmail."

Its working fine when i use simple text format for example "abc@google.com,xyz@google.com"

but when I use a list of email in array called `email_list_S1` it gives me error.

Mentioned below is my code:-

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('19zdQSZFX7gkkjhkhkhhklhklhlxEw8dhtIkzv7mUOI');
var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
var lastR = sh.getLastRow()
var data2 = sh.getRange("A4:QC"+lastR).getValues();
  
var email_list_S1 = data2.filter(function(item){return item[15]=="ON" && item[9]=="S1" && item[436] =="";}).map(elem => elem[0]);
  
MailApp.sendEmail(email_list_S1,"Missing Login Detail S1 Shift Reminder!!"+" ["+today+"]", "",
{htmlBody: "Hello All, <br><br>"+"You are receiving this mail because you have missed to log-in." 
+ "<br><br>"+'Please click the link attached '
+ '<a href=\"' +"https://script.google.com/a/google.com/macros/s/k/exec?v=home"+ '">here</a>'+" and mark your attendance."+'<br><br>Thank You'});
```

Comment: Replace `getValues` with `getDisplayValues`

Comment: I just tried that but it does not work same error.

Comment: To understand what is wrong in your code you can see what is the value of `email_list_S1`.  After you define it, run `console.log(email_list_S1)` and then go to View->Logs or execution page to see its value. That is the logic in every programming language. When a function does not work because the type of inputs don't match the type of arguments, you always print or log the arguments to see if they contain what you want them to contain. It is common sense.

Comment: I have already seen those values and it goes like this:- [abc@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com,pqr@gmail.com....and so on]

Comment: cool, then can you replace `email_list_S1` with `email_list_S1.toString()` and let me know if it worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issues / Explanation:**

- `email_list_S1` is an array with emails, but the first argument of
  [sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body) accepts a string of email/s.
- You need to convert `email_list_S1` to string and you can use [Array.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) to accomplish that.

---

**Solution:**

Replace:

`MailApp.sendEmail(email_list_S1,..)`

with

`MailApp.sendEmail(email_list_S1.toString(),..)`